# Adding unnumbered task in MS Project 2013

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

I need to add a task to my WBS/Gantt Chart in MS Project, but not number it as it is a task (Kickoff meeting) that I want to fall under the heading: Project Administration. I need this to be a general task that is not part of the Project WBS I have created but somehow still show up on it as a general item.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is your project structured as a flat WBS where all tasks are at the same level, or do you indent tasks beneath others to form headings / groups? Have you considered whether you could simply include this as a lower level (indented) task within a higher level "Project Administration" group, and simply collapse the group so that everything in it shows up under the ingle "Project Administration" rolled up task?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the WBS or Outline numbers will automatically number the task.  You can use a spare text field (text1) to set up your own WBS codes and simply skip adding one to the task in question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have generated a WBS in the WBS field of MS Project, all tasks/lines will be numbered.  If I need to get around this by not adding tasks to the overall project WBS, then I have a section at the top of my schedule where I put Program Milestones that are linked to my program schedule below.  This way I can add as many milestones as I need and will not change the overall structure of the agreed upon program schedule.  It seems to give me some flexibility.  Example:

[image]